# Git remote branch

Tags: git, git-remote

Today I try to track a remote branch (specifically, Mapbox-ios-sdk's 23-callouts.

So, what's the difference between the following three commands:

`git checkout remotes/origin/23-callouts`

`git checkout -b remotes/origin/23-callouts`

`git checkout -b 23-callouts remotes/origin/23-callouts`

The first command gives me a "(no branch)". My second command is actually a mistake I made where my third command was intended and I was surprised it goes through, and I don't know what happen there. The third command would give me what's called a "remote tracking branch", but how is that different from the second or the first? I've also seen "git checkout --track" is that the same thing as the third command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can found the answer via `git help checkout` & `git help branch`

```
git checkout remotes/origin/23-callouts
```

Try to checkout a local branch named 'remotes/origin/23-callouts', so this is not you want

```
git checkout -b remotes/origin/23-callouts
```

Try to create a new local branch named 'remotes/origin/23-callouts' base on HEAD. so this is not you want neither.

```
git checkout -b 23-callouts remotes/origin/23-callouts
```

Try to create a new local branch named '23-callouts' base on remotes branch. So it's correct

about `git checkout --track`, it's almost the same, for both you got a local branch tracking with remote one, the only difference is the name of the local branch.

```
git checkout --track remotes/origin/23-callouts
```

is same as the third command. The local branch is named *23-callouts*

Via third command, you can change the name of local branch by change the param after `-b`

Comment: So for the first 2 commands, despite the name being "remotes/origin/23-callouts", it has nothing to do with remote?